# Create License agreement screen in OSX

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I am trying to implement license agreement as shown in the attached image, I can create a new WindowController and design in the same way, but i want to know if we have any default screens in Xcode to do this kind of stuff, as i noticed that most of the apps have similar kind of design.
[image]

Comment: "i noticed that most of the apps have similar kind of design. "  Which app has one?  I have never seen one with a desktop application.  I have seen one with an application installer.

Comment: @ElTomato i noticed the same design in VMWare license agreement and in FileZilla license agreement. I saw both of them when i tried to install from .dmg file.

Comment: So who is running the show?  VMWare?  FileZilla?  Or their installers?

Comment: @ElTomato sorry not really sure what you are asking, all i need is do we have any default screens/windows to create this kind of screen or should i create my own windowcontroller and design the same way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161566/discussion-between-shiva-kumar-and-el-tomato).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no default UI Element for it, nor is there a well known community option. Best option is to design your own.

Comment: @lura Gutu, Thanks for your response. Looks like there is no default Element/Screen/WindowController like this, I will create a new WindowController and design in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

That's a disk mount license agreement. You can embed a license agreement into a DMG disk image, to be displayed with this screen when a user mounts the image.

[image: DMG license agreement]

If your application is in `example/Example.app`, you can create `example.dmg`, embedding `EULA.txt` into it as follows:

```
hdiutil create -srcfolder example/ -volname "Example" "example.dmg"
./eula_into_dmg.sh "example.dmg" "EULA.txt"
# you should also codesign the dmg if you're going to distribute it:
codesign -s "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" -v "$dmg"
```

This is `eula_into_dmg.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -u

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <dmg> <license>"
    exit 1
fi

prefix=$(base64 -D <<<\
H4sIAJtVUFoCA4VWW2vbSBh9bn7Fh3ahbci6o9FcLPahJJIMBbcNjaH7qjpyYupaiyW3pGX/+55vpJF1\
ianBYmTjo/Ody4zv8zqnl6v3t8uX9CqU8ysKlrfbdfCafl28+DMII6XIaGPIhFaTSawiKVSCW5ORsfxZ\
aGxAvdebS5qlxSY/7mpa5vuHY/5Al28YzWgpSMWAVEpb0hIroVVEZsFAGcDVQkVjtILepennT+ksKY/7\
+mPSoqlM4+dKXpO8dhfQ0hE+U5G4IRvZGBcpxmgfVrNLvJZ3q2RWPVXkuSUmBAVjeb4YBMFNWy2xCjFp\
YhZkIhOO0XYY0NPbleu8Q8OkVhrtKDQzSyHnmJS1NBYza6smaHQoKsDRq3KzqYq6RZMCPwIaKKRAi3SE\
i8DlJGMoIjlGo82h/EZaCOHoSY+WGkk2tmws0E6DW80rC9LRQk24/fXlqS7cvDC0eJu2aK1GQnkXcFGJ\
jkiD3ABjgMaEWhsyRvrv74uLe5dFjh+yyLTbEGIlCG9JfjW6KLeahHD0Gj7mbvXpj/YxyHy2f9htq0f6\
cqzrcl8FpycbEqnSjUCQijNl5vDSyQcbrYrCZ57sAeuiqsNWKkSd9bWSG6VJzLlbMUchZPU5LUYLPUG7\
fjgUxSzdVrlbeOEFA8WooVUCKUA4yRpgyExmuFj4EBszRrs9bPf17C7/XoDlz3ebLmKoi6shwtZniS8s\
swTV+bRM9FQeydGiH9v60ZfJKmjk0oWV5tHSpggu/o14cxOP0erHAoIdvlVUbnCz9WhRE9OYG+j2CW6P\
TJhq1H1xM0araLddF/uquKI1Vl+7SSUC21Mctw2jBT8mZEg8ZjJp4GwIqC4pX6+LjhvI+IGcWlEzpFWs\
W+hklNmEW+WGrcpN/SM/dJ6Cm3Cu0cAPzy3DDmDVMy4QfGQn7kval3W3pfWHZLVstyc50qyDmrrg7Lyi\
f7EVVRSkJxeGucikPFPv4aRNaINz7ZOn9g1bZ6etGxbofOuaxvjWnakZDQs0PcJ835rG+NZNanbzjGGT\
HaHt26/Wp+6YOFMzGhZojHbqW9MY79CZmtGwQGO0U9+axnhuvZo9Exyv5RjN9a3NDttwOvoHNXOyR3wb\
GvybSNqZJ0e/69t2X9X5bgeK/T8SiMSCj1JF1rIpsjFFNAe4MdOe9AvHlfG6xdwrdxYqrOBfxk6q0VY4\
RusVLu/lTbpZXLbc+cDaSznJ4BitVziXu4Fu2W+bNtFtdNytsn9W0+PubnntSvc/iogHYQYKAAA= | gunzip -)

suffix=$(base64 -D <<<\
H4sIANNVUFoCA6u15uJKSSxJVFAvLqnMUVfQMDUwMNBRUHLNS8/JLM5QCPZxVNJUqObiVFECShgrAAkD\
OOEMIiyBhKEJQkJJAQnoaynowcAxCKWgpQ81zUABgzAyRzMXp2nqEBNhphliMw3JXEewuThNAwEtZLeh\
+wqNQDEIbtoxZONAZtVacwEAUriwzWEBAAA= | gunzip -)

temp=$(mktemp)
echo -n "$prefix" > "$temp"
cat "$2" | dd conv=swab | hexdump -v -e '8/2 "%04x " "\n"' | sed -e 's/ *$//' -e 's/^/        $"/' -e 's/$/"/' >> "$temp"
echo -n "$suffix" >> "$temp"

hdiutil unflatten "$1"
Rez -a "$temp" -o "$1"
hdiutil flatten "$1"
rm "$temp"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. Could you briefly explain the content of the script? Have you created it with some tool? Can the text on the left be customized as well? I'm trying to check what's possible here.

Comment: The script is generating input for the `Rez` tool, which embeds the license text into the dmg near the end of the script. If you add `cat "$temp"` before the `rm "$temp"` at the end, you can see the file format Rez is expecting. Yes, I believe you can customize the text on the left, you just need to generate that section of the Rez input as well (which is currently hardcoded in the base64 sections of the shell script for convenience)